# Spring Boot not blocking request to the endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication

Im having an issue with spring boot. I am trying to block one specific endpoint called `/users/name/` but when i configure it on httpSecurity I can still call the endpoint. I need to block this specific endpoint below is my code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthConfigClass extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/name/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin")
        .password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

And this is the RestController. Note please that the intention of this app is to make it vulnerable to attacks like the OWASP TOP API so  no worries about security issues please tough I accept suggestions.

```
@Api(value="Users Endpoint and maintenance only for prvileged users")
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class RestControllerMain {

    private final  UserRespository userRespository;
    @Autowired
    public RestControllerMain(UserRespository userRespository) {
        this.userRespository = userRespository;
    }
    //Excessive Data Exposure OWASP TOP 10 
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRespository.findAll();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void UserInsert(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRespository.save(user);
    }
    //null pointer exception and SQL injection OWASP TOP 10 API.
    @RequestMapping(value="/name/{user}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mainUser(@PathVariable ("user")String username) {
        if(!username.matches("/[\\t\\r\\n]|(--[^\\r\\n]*)|(\\/\\*[\\w\\W]*?(?=\\*)\\*\\/)/gi\n" )) {
        return "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘‘VALUE’’.";
        }
        return "SQL Injection not found";
        }
    //XSS Also in the OWASP TOP API.
    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMeUSer(@RequestBody User user) {
    return "Nice to meet you" + user.getName();
    }
    // OWASP TOP 10 API. Broken Object Level
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}")
    public Optional<User> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {  
        return userRespository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Please help me figure this I ended up following a tutorial.

Comment: You are saying you want to protect the /users/name/ path, so you configured it in the security section. So far so good, but I don't see that endpoint in your controller. You have GET /users, POST /users, GET /users/name/{user}, GET /users/search and GET /users/{id}. Do you want to protect everything after /users/name, like /users/name/{user}?

Comment: @RequestMapping("/users") first three lines

Comment: Please include a picture of what you are receiving when you call the enpoint you want to block

Comment: You have .permitAll() for /users/name endpoint, does it not it allow requests to that endpoint

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to require authentication for **"users/name/{user}"** endpoint, but your configuration states

```
.antMatchers("/users/name/")
```

whereas it should be

```
.antMatchers("/users/name/**")
```

where "**" means **any** matching pattern. But you if want to grant access after checking the privileges, as you stated in the description of controller, you should configure Spring's authorization and add

```
@Secured("ROLE_VIEWER, ROLE_ADMIN")
```

before service or controller methods, which will block any user who doesn't have those roles.